# Any correlation between strong animal breed preferences and latent racism?

Tags: preferences, racism

Here by "latent racism" I mean the tendency, subconscious or otherwise, to judge people according to their race, rather than their individual character. Basically, generalization of certain traits onto a specific race/ethnicity and casually applying said stereotypical trait when evaluating an individual.

By "strong animal breed preferences" I mean overt opinions such as "I like dogs, but all pit bulls must be abolished", etc. Basically, generalization of certain traits onto an entire specific breed and casually applying said stereotypical traits when evaluating an individual animal.

I wonder whether anybody tried to measure whether a correlation between a strong animal breed preference and latent racism exists. Are people who have such preferences more likely to harbor racist beliefs or not?